# Adding elements to the diagonal of a matrix that is not square in R

Tags: r, matrix

I want to be able to add a value (in my code `nug`) to the i,j entry of a matrix where i = j (so like a Kronecker delta function).  Its very easy to do when the matrix is square (see my code below) however I am not sure how to do it in one line when the matrix is not square

```
nug = 2
R = tau + diag(nug,nrow(tau))
```

The above code works when tau is a square matrix but now imagine that `tau` is not square.  How would I add `nug` to each of the i,j elements of `tau` where i = j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2)
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
diag(m) <- diag(m) + 1:2
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
m[col(m)==row(m)] <- m[col(m)==row(m)] +nug
```

Using a matrix of zeros to show this:

```
m <- matrix(rep(0,6), ncol = 2)
> m[col(m)==row(m)] <- m[col(m)==row(m)] +2
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    0
[2,]    0    2
[3,]    0    0
```